# wimax client can not ping the base station

Tags: connection, wimax

I have a problem with Beceem wimax dongle on linux (ubuntu 12.04). The driver has been installed successfully and can detect the signal sent from the base station.  But the question is that the client with the wimax dongle can not ping the base station, and any other clients as well.

Description: This dongle works well  on the Windows 7 OS when ping to both the base station and other clients. But it is not case on linux. To address it, I was trying to track the connection status with the help of "wimaxd" and "wimaxc".  Below is the detailed information

sudo wimaxc -i
Beceem CM Server Version 1.1.6.0

> > > search

Network search returned 1 base station.

Idx BSID                      Pre       Freq      BW  RSSI  CINR

0  01:01:44:51:db:00:11:02 0x01 2596.000  10.000   -69    24

> > > connect 0

connect command is currently disabled: already connected

> > > status

Link status  LINKUP ACHIEVED

Connection time  0:0:8

Server up time   0:1:45

Base Station ID  44:51:DB:00:11:02

Preamble Index   1

UL Cell ID   1

RSSI Mean    -69 dBm

CINR Mean    23 dB

UL Center Freq   2596000 kHz

DL Center Freq   2596000 kHz

> > > cmstats

Connection attempts            5

Conn OK                   3

Percent OK                60%

**But the problem is when I try to verify the link connection via ping, all the packets sent by the client are lost as shown below.**

0 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9054ms

Please any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not figured it out yet, try checking your DNS settings.  I use `4.2.2.1` and `4.2.2.6` for my DNS servers. The Wimax modem I have likes to forward it's own internal address as the only DNS server. I prefer nano as ana editor, but use the one of your choice.

```
sudo nano resolv.conf
```

Add the following 2 lines:

```
nameserver 4.2.2.1
nameserver 4.2.2.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you would have resolved the issue. However, here are few tips.

The output of ping '0 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9054ms' means that packets did not go out.

It can be due to various reasons :
1. Check whether the interface is disabled via some other configurations 
2. Check the network settings -
   a. May be the default gateway in your route table is not set or proper. 
   b. Also check if the output of ifconfig -a and cat /etc/resolv.conf are properly associated 
3. Check the interface card and if applicable , check the connector.